# Passing value from jquery to mvc controller

Tags: jquery

My link:

```
<span class="list-subtitle"><span class="place-right icon-flag-2 fg-red smaller" onclick="ShowMessage('@item.MessageId');">23</span>
```

My Jquery:

```
<script>
function ShowMessage(msgid) {
      alert("Hello" + msgid);
      $.Dialog({
          overlay: false,
          shadow: true,
          flat: false,
          title: 'Studidesk - Conversations',
          content: '',
          onShow: function (_dialog) {
              var html = [
                  '<iframe width="800" height="480" src="/Channel/Comments/' + msgid +'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'
              ].join("");

              $.Dialog.content(html);
          }
      });          
  }
</script>
```

My Controller(Get)

```
public ActionResult Comments(string msgid )
   {
       var balObject = new BusinessLogic();
       List<StudiMessageDetails> comments = new List<StudiMessageDetails>();
       comments = balObject.FetchComment(msgid );
       return PartialView("_commentsPost", comments);
   }
```

Though the query sends the control to my action method

```
public ActionResult Comments(string msgid ),
```

it does not have value msgid , can anybody help me to pass  msgid present in

```
<span class="list-subtitle"><span class="place-right icon-flag-2 fg-red smaller" onclick="ShowMessage('@item.MessageId');">23</span>
```

to action method..

Jquery is triggered when I click :

```
<span class="list-subtitle"><span class="place-right icon-flag-2 fg-red smaller" onclick="ShowMessage('@item.MessageId');">23</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

To call your action like that, you need to define route. If you have not defined a route yet, you can call it like this:

```
<script>
    function ShowMessage(msgid) {
          alert("Hello" + msgid);
          $.Dialog({
              overlay: false,
              shadow: true,
              flat: false,
              title: 'Studidesk - Conversations',
              content: '',
              onShow: function (_dialog) {
                  var html = [
                      '<iframe width="800" height="480" src="/Channel/Comments?msgid=' + msgid +'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'
                  ].join("");

                  $.Dialog.content(html);
              }
          });          
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: @MichaelPhilips I'm glad that helped. Don't forget to mark asnwers when they work for you. :)

Comment: Can I pass two values on click like this:

Comment: @MichaelPhilips Yes, you can.